# Rabbit MQ Stomp sending ERROR message for NACK/ACK

Tags: rabbitmq, stomp

I am sending STOMP messages to Rabbit MQ client. It is working, but sending ERROR messages for NACK/ACK.
Below are the message sequence.
NACK
requeue:False
message-id:T_141414@@session-LqaSmsWbsrq4y1EkEDS4RQ@@1
subscription:141414
id:141414

ERROR
content-length:40
content-type:text/plain
message:Invalid header
version:1.0,1.1,1.2
content-length:40

"NACK" must include a valid "id" header

Comment: How are you setting the message ID? Here's an example of how the STOMP plugin does it: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-stomp/blob/master/test/src/ack.py#L163

Comment: Please format the STOMP traffic so the headers are readable

Comment: Which STOMP version does the connection use?